# Calculate the probability such that out of the $10$ coin flips at least $M$ flips were tails, given that there were at least $M$ identical results

Tags: probability

Say I toss $10$ unfair coins where $P(\text{tails}) = p$ and $p > 0.5$.

I want to calculate the probability such that out of the $10$ coin flips **at least $M$ flips** were tails, given that **there were at least $M$ identical results**.

My solution was as follows :
Let $X$ be the number of tails results and $Y$ be the number of heads results.
I tried to calculate 
$$P(X\geq M \mid (X\geq M)\cup(Y\geq M)) = \frac{P(X\geq M)}{ P((X\geq M)\cup (Y\geq M))}$$ where $P(X\geq M) = \binom{10}{M} p^M (1-p)^{10-M}$ and $P(Y\geq M)$ can be calculated in the same way.

Is $P((X\geq M)\cup (Y\geq M)) = P(X\geq M) + P(Y\geq M))$?

Is this solution is correct? am I missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: Please verify my edits. Also, see the detailed formatting tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**
   $$\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)} $$
where

> - Event $A$ is **at least M flips are tails**.
> - Event $B$ is **there are at least M identical results**.

$$\Pr(B) = \Pr(\text{at least M tails})+ \Pr(\text{at least M heads})-\Pr(\text{at least M tails and at least M heads})$$

and
$$\begin{align}\\
\Pr(\text{at least M tails})&=\Pr(\text{M tails})+\Pr(\text{M+1 tails})+\cdots+\Pr(\text{10 tails})\\
&=\binom{10}{M}p^M(1-p)^{10-M}+\binom{10}{M+1}p^{M+1}(1-p)^{9-M}+\cdots+\binom{10}{10}p^{10}(1-p)^0\end{align}$$

Notice that since here $A\subset B$, then $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)$ and the final result becomes $\frac{\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B)}$.

Comment: I Just realized I did not understood the question well enough, I edited the question. I think that the only adjustment to make from your solution is that now $Pr(A∩B)$ equal to $P(A)$ isn't it?

Comment: care to elaborate please? If I know that there are M identical results and I want at least M tails why do I take 8 into consideration?

Comment: final answer to my entire calculations? I can't see how this adds up.. can you please exaplain with the conditional probability formula? the bottom part I understand but the upper part is still vague

Comment: I have updated the answer according to the changes in the question.

Comment: How to calculate Pr(at least M tails and at least M heads) ? is it just $p^{M}(1-p)^{M}$?
and what about the other formula $Pr(B)=Pr(tails)Pr(at least M tails)+Pr(heads)Pr(at least M heads)$ what was wrong with this one ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of tails results, $Y$ be the number of identical results.

$$P(X = 0, Y >= 8) = P(X = 0)$$
$$P(X = 1, Y >= 8) = P(X = 1)$$
$$P(X = 2, Y >= 8) = P(X = 2)$$
$$P(X = 3, Y >= 8) = 0$$
$$...$$
$$P(X = 7, Y >= 8) = 0$$
$$P(X = 8, Y >= 8) = P(X = 8)$$
$$P(X = 9, Y >= 8) = P(X = 9)$$
$$P(X = 10, Y >= 8) = P(X = 10)$$

You want to calculate $P_M=P(X >= M, Y >= 8)$.

For $M >= 8$ the result is:

$$P_M = \sum_{k=M}^{10} P(X=k)$$

For $M > 2$ and $M<8$ the result is:

$$P_M = \sum_{k=8}^{10} P(X=k)$$

For $M <= 2$ the result is:

$$P_M = \sum_{k=M}^{2} P(X=k) + \sum_{k=8}^{10} P(X=k)$$

where:

$$P(X=k) = {{10}\choose{k}} p^k (1-p)^{10-k}$$

If you introduce constant $a_k$ so that:

$a_k=1$ for $k=0,1,2,8,9,10$ and

$a_k=0$ for $k=3,4,5,6,7$

...you can write all three results in a simple form:

$$P_M = \sum_{k=M}^{10} a_k{{10}\choose{k}} p^k (1-p)^{10-k}$$

Comment: Just realized I did not understood the question well enough, I edited the question can you please edit the answer accordingly? Thanks